# shared *.xlam on network drive - call subs and functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have been scouring the forum for a solution to my challenge below, bur unfortunately without any luck. I have written some subs and functions, that I need to make available to my colleagues and that I would like to be able to update centrally. In order to do that, following this brilliant article, https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?152-Deploying-Add-ins-in-a-Network-Environment , I have made a sheet that can deploy my code to an *.xlam on our network drive along with code to install the Add In on the users excel. To allow the users to call the subs/functions in the *.xlam, I have added a reference to the workbook-template where the subs/functions are needed.

But, as the Add In is located on the network drive, it will not always be available, and the user will get the compile error "Can't find the project or library".

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to still use the reference method, but work around the "Can't find the project or library"-error?
2. Is there a better way for the users to call functions from the Add In?
3. And the big one: Should i share and update to code in a completely different manner?

Best regards
Knekse

Answer (score 0):

Because:

1. An add-in can load another add-in. Workbooks.Open(Filename:=pathToFile & addinFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
2. The network resource will not always be reachable.

You might try using a stub add-in on the client machines.

This stub can:

1. Check whether a desired add-in is available on the network, and load if possible.
2. Option A: Provide stub functions/subs that call the real routines in the desired add-in when it's available, and otherwise return a suitable failure status or default message.
3. Option B: Automatically copy the desired add-in to a cache on the local machine and add load the cached copy if needed.

By keeping the stub simple and well tested, it need not be frequently changed, so you won't lose the whole benefit of keeping the main add-in on the network.

Note that there is no need to add the networked add-in to the AddIns/AddIns2 collection; you can just use  Workbooks.Open(pathToAddIn, ReadOnly:=True). It will not show up in ‹‹File › Options › Add-Ins›› when opened this way. Consequently, if you want to unload or reload the add-in without closing Excel, either your stub add-in should provide a way to do this, or you will need to do it with VBA (such as in the Immediate window of the VBA editor).

Comment: Hi Ilsi. thanks for the input. I just need a little more clarification ;)

So you're saying that it would be a good idea to have a local (the stub, and very simple) add in on the users computer to supplement the network add in.
Then use the stub add in to (try) load the network add in and act accordingly?

Comment: C'est vrai. Yes. For example, the stub contains stubfoo(), and stubfoo() asks the VBA host to On Error GoTo missingAddin:Application.Run("mainfoo")